# Inline elements implementation

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

I want to create `Text` components and to display them in a row , like `span` elements in html. If i'm doing it this way:

```
<View>
  <Text> Start here, </Text> <Text> finish here </Text>
</View>
```

line is broken between them and it looks like:

> Start here,
>   finish here

How can i prevent line breaking and display them on the same line?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Just set the correct [`flexDirection`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flexdirection). Default is `column`.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
 <Text> Start here, </Text> <Text> finish here </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: In my case, this did not work until each Text element was wrapped in it's own view inside of the outer (flexbox) view.

Comment: This does not handle wrapping of text. You will need to handle this with @cherniv 's answer

Comment: Yeah this doesn't answer the question, this creates a column / row like structure, not a flowing inline style

Comment: For anyone using react native base, <Flex> and <HStack> also work.

Answer (score 39):

[`Text`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#content) components are inline when wrapping them with another `Text` element, like:

```
<Text>
   <Text>We</Text><Text>Are</Text><Text>Inline</Text>
</Text>
```

Comment: Note : U won't be able to padding/margin the child text using this solution.

Comment: Can't add border either...